# How to set InputTransparent as true for parent, not for children

Tags: xaml, layout, xamarin.forms

I am having one stacklayout and one button inside that. I want to click through that stacklayout, and also that button click.

I tried setting InputTransparent as true for StackLayout and then setting same as false for button. It did not work. Whatever applied at parent level is set to all children inside it.

```
<StackLayout InputTransparent="True">
    <Button Text="Submit" InputTransparent="False"/>
</StackLayout>
```

I expect button to be clicked, as well as element behind StackLayout should be clickable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Layouts have a property CascadeInputTransparent. When true, child views inherit their parent's input transparency. When false, child views do not inherit the input transparency of the layout where Cascade is set.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layout.cascadeinputtransparent?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: This answer right here is godlike!! Thanks. Especially when you have to develop a Xamarin app with a static header that always shows while the user can scroll content underneath.

Answer (score 5):

Use `CascadeInputTransparent`.

```html
<StackLayout InputTransparent="True" CascadeInputTransparent="False">
   <Button Text="Submit"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

InputTransparent gets or sets a value indicating whether this element should be involved in the user interaction cycle.
You set StackLayout InputTransparent to true, which means "don't allow this view to receive any input". If you set that on a parent view then none of its children should receive touches either.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of this. I am asking if there is any way to overwrite that behaviour .

Comment: Forget about input transparent and use tap gesture for stack layout and click for button. (i think you want to click both of them and perform some task, if I m wrong please explain a little bit more)